# Selecting a token using JSON.NET and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, json.net

I have the following XML in C# like so:

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<!--PowerStats Table Model Paramter Template Ver 1.0 Created on 11/19/2013-->" +
        "<paramFile version=\"1.0\" createdBy=\"PowerStats v1.0\">" +
        "    <DSNumber value=\"82\" />" +
        "</parmFile>" +
        "<paramFile version=\"2.0\" createdBy=\"PowerStats v2.0\">" +
        "    <DSNumber value=\"83\" />" +
        "</parmFile>";
```

Then I create the JSON to test (which) works fine:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xml);
    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc).Replace("\"@", "\"");
```

But using JToken how do I get the first paramFile version and the second with the code below?  I keep getting null.

```
    JToken token = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

    string paramFile = (string)token.SelectToken("paramFile[0].version");

    Response.Write(paramFile);
```

Comment: I'm surprised that doesn't throw an exception, seeing that you don't have a single root element in the XML. Did you try printing `jsonText` to see how it is structured?

Comment: you're right it does. And the code works if there are 2 paramFiles with a root around them. I need to figure out how many paramFiles are there to do either root.paramFile.version or root.paramFile[0].version

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Json.NET to parse XML? Why can't you get your data directly from the XML DOM?

Comment: I am converting all of our XML to JSON per architects request for our app

Comment: So eventually there will be no XML at all

Answer (score 0):

Like we figured in the comments, since you don't have a root element `SerializeXmlNode` only takes the first element so it doesn't create an array.

If you can modify the XML, you can [add an attribute that tells `SerializeXmlNode` to always convert `paramFile`s to array - even if there is only one](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertXmlToJsonForceArray.htm).

If you primary goal is to convert lots of XMLs  to JSON, I'm going to suggest a different approach.

XML can not be correctly converted automatically to JSON because the structures of XML and JSON are inherently different. Either [the result JSON will look weird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JsonML), or like in your case - won't always be correct.

The bright side is that XML can be converted to JSON if you have a schema. I'm not talking about XmlSchema or JsonSchema(though you might find a tool that does the conversion using those) - I'm talking about any definition of how the data represented by the XML/JSON should be structured. If you have a conversion that takes a schema into account, you can have a correct automatic conversion.

Now, the easiest thing you can use as schema is C# classes:

1. Create a class structure that represents the data you want to convert.
2. Use [XmlSerializer.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the XML to objects.
3. Use [JToken.FromObject](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) to convert the objects to JSON.

The downside is that you have to write classes that represent all the data, but this might be a hidden bonus as these classes will surely come in handy quite often in the future. After all - they do represent data structures used in your app...